# calculate number of days difference with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, sum

Hi I was wondering how I can calculate the number of days difference based on todays date. I would like to create a table like the following:

```
    >50 >40 >30
Agent A         
Agent B
```

based on this data:

```
Agent | Work Completed
A | 12/07/2017
B | 01/03/2017
A | 12/06/2017
```

Result should be:

```
         >50  >40  >30
Agent A  0    1    0            
Agent B  1    0    0
```

I have tried a sumif and sumproduct but as I have a field with todays date (=today()) and then I am minusing the 2, this doesn't work.

Would really appreciate some advice.

Comment: Link a googledocs spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/ with what you've got so far . You can upload an Excel spreadsheet by using file > import > upload

Comment: http://pakaccountants.com/aging-analysis-reports-using-excel-how-to/ This may give you some inspiration too

Comment: if cell A1 contained a date, cell A2 could contain a formula =A1-TODAY().

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lUedt1gRyyTqjNPH3FrkNibjoKbrWfJXa1nnpeqMAls/edit?usp=sharing)
It caters for future dates, things within 30, 60, 90, or more days old.
**Data** creates random list of dates relative to today.
[image]
**Forumulae**
[image]