# Filtering specific individual dates in PivotTables with changing input

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table

How do I filter data for specific individual dates in a PivotTable? The input is changed on a weekly basis and therefore the specific desired dates will change every week. I have data for every business day. And I want to retrieve data from the most recent business day, 5 business days before that, 30 business days before that and 90 business days before that. How do I go about this?

Comment: Did either of the answers below solve the issue? If so, can you please mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want an 'Aging Report' If you Google on 'Excel Aging Report', you should be able to find something. use of TODAY() in formula is part of answer. I also did something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45144620/495157). It didn't involve Pivot tables.. But it should help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the code in my answer at [Filtering pivot table with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004607/filtering-pivot-table-with-vba)

That code lets you programatically filter a Pivot RowField or ColumnField by specifying an interval type (e.g. days, weeks, months, quarters, years) as well as an interval count (e.g. 7, -7). It has an optional argument vRelativeTo field which counts back/foward from the youngest/oldest item depending on whether lNumber is positive/negative.

It leverages off the inbuilt DateFilters functionality, and as such does not
work on RowFields.